# Correct way to assign a value to a cell in a for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The code works by cycling through every row and calling an 'is_color' function. The function checks values in the ith row and assigns a color, 'blue' for example, if the condition is met

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def is_color(df):

    df['color'] = np.nan
    def blue(i):
        is_blue = True # some more complex condition
        if is_blue:
            #df['color'].iloc[i] = 'blue'
            df.set_value(i, 'color', 'blue')

    for i in range(len(df)):

        blue(i)

        # not included i this example
        #green(i)  
        #orange(i)
        #purple(i)
        #yellow(i)

    return df
```

I was originally doing `df['color'].iloc[i] = 'blue'` which worked but threw a `SettingWithCopyWarning` I need to make it production ready, I tried `df.set_value(i, 'color', 'blue')` however that throws a `ValueError: could not convert string to float: blue` i need to do it like this i think:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def is_color(df):

    df['color'] = np.nan
    def blue(i, df):
        is_blue = True # some more complex condition
        if is_blue:
            #df['color'].iloc[i] = 'blue'
            return df.set_value(i, 'color', 'blue')
        return df

    for i in range(len(df)):

        df = blue(i, df)

        # not included i this example
        #df = green(i, df)  
        #df = orange(i, df)

    return df
```

I feel like my original code was cleaner though, is there a prettier way to do this ?

Comment: can you show us the sample of your dataframe?

Comment: You need change `df['color'] = np.nan` to `df['color'] = ''` or remove it.

Comment: But do you really need loop?

Answer (score 0):

If many conditions is possible use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with custom function with `if`, `elif` and `else`:

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,31],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

print (df)

def is_color(x):
    if x < 15:
        x = 'blue'
    elif (x > 15) and (x < 25):
        x = 'green'
    else:
        x = 'nothing'
    return (x)


df['color'] = df['A'].apply(is_color)
print (df)
    A  B    color
0  10  4     blue
1  20  5    green
2  31  6  nothing
```

Similar solution:

```
def is_color(x):
    a = 'nothing'
    if x < 15:
        a = 'blue'
    if (x > 15) and (x < 25):
        a = 'green'
    return (a)


df['color'] = df['A'].apply(is_color)
print (df)
    A  B    color
0  10  4     blue
1  20  5    green
2  31  6  nothing
```